# Getting Error when start to Debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

When I debug my ASP.NET Web Site I get the following error:

> The files `"/BookIt.Web/App_Code/VBCode/vCalendar.vb"` and `"/BookIt.Web/App_Code/CSCode/WebGrid/user/BenutzerCollection.cs"` use different languages​​. This is not allowed, because they must be compiled together.

I don't know how to fix that.

Someone can help me?

Stacktrace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Die Dateien "/BookIt.Web/App_Code/VBCode/QueryStringModule.vb" und "/BookIt.Web/App_Code/CSCode/Webgrid/Dienstleistung/Servicegruppe.cs" verwenden unterschiedliche Sprachen. Dies ist nicht zulässig, weil sie gemeinsam kompiliert werden müssen.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +452
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +42
   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) +640
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories) +125
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories() +265
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +320

[HttpException (0x80004005): Die Dateien "/BookIt.Web/App_Code/VBCode/QueryStringModule.vb" und "/BookIt.Web/App_Code/CSCode/Webgrid/Dienstleistung/Servicegruppe.cs" verwenden unterschiedliche Sprachen. Dies ist nicht zulässig, weil sie gemeinsam kompiliert werden müssen.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) +729

[HttpException (0x80004005): Die Dateien "/BookIt.Web/App_Code/VBCode/QueryStringModule.vb" und "/BookIt.Web/App_Code/CSCode/Webgrid/Dienstleistung/Servicegruppe.cs" verwenden unterschiedliche Sprachen. Dies ist nicht zulässig, weil sie gemeinsam kompiliert werden müssen.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8921851
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +259
```

Comment: @J.Steen You should add this as an answer, because.. it is an answer.

Comment: @user1527329 Yeah, realised that as I hit "add comment". ;)

Comment: The error is already explaining to you what's happening, what's the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you can't mix languages in the same project. You can have a VB.NET project and a C# project in the same solution, one referencing the other. You use *one* compiler to compile a single project.

You can have code from several languages in the same project if the other languages are included as `Build Action: Content`, not `Build Action: Compile`. Of course, you won't be able to use classes and logic from those files.

Code files in the `App_Code` folder will, however, be automatically compiled

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(v=vs.80).aspx
>
> Because the source code in the App_Code folder is compiled into a single assembly, all the files in the App_Code folder must be in the same programming language. For example, the App_Code folder cannot include source code in both Visual Basic and C#.
>
> However, you can configure your Web application to treat subfolders of the App_Code folder as separate compilable units. Each folder can then contain source code in a different programming language. The configuration is specified by creating a codeSubDirectories element in the compilation element of the Web.config file and adding a reference to the subfolder. The following example illustrates how you would configure subfolders named VBCode and CSCode to compile into separate assemblies:

```
<compilation debug="false">
    <codeSubDirectories>
        <add directoryName="VBCode" />
        <add directoryName="CSCode" />
    </codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>
```

Comment: It worked the whole time. I loaded an Update over our company SVN, since i have done this, the error appear

Comment: Someone else added code of another type to the project then. Since you have SVN, you can look at the differences since the revision that worked for you, and determine what's been done.

Comment: i have two folders in the App-Code. CSCode and VBCode and in the webconfig a added also: <compilation debug="false">
    <codeSubDirectories>
        <add directoryName="VBCode" />
        <add directoryName="CSCode" />
    </codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>. so i don#t know whats the problem

Comment: Well, again. Check the changes since the revision that worked for you.

Comment: And, uh, I'm curious. What happens if you set `debug` to `true`?

Comment: Yeah that was the Problem. I talked to my superior, he changed it in the last revision. Now it works again :). Thanks for help :)